# Run remote PHP from batch file

Tags: php, batch-file

I have a batch file that does a lot of stuff, then at the end needs to call a URL and pass it a querystring. The remote file in turn just does some PHP stuff and doesn't really need to give any output.

How can I go about doing it? Something just like `run http://myurl.com/myfile.php?ID=123`? Can't find it anywhere. I don't need to open a browser, however if I have to I will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using curl.

[See here](http://linux-journal.blogspot.com/2005/04/curl-examples.html).

It also runs in Windows (not sure which OS you're talking about)

Comment: Yep windows... good point, I was already using cURL to run the batch file.. why didnt I think of that

Comment: @rickyduck FYI there is also a Windoze port of [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)